# PowerApps If textfield is blank do not patch else patch

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am writing a Patch but before patching I need to check some textfield's and dropdowns are NOT blank. I can't get the syntax to work and below is my code

`If(!IsBlank(TextInput5_1.Text), "true", "true"), Patch(BookingTest,
{ Title: title, EventDate: TextInput5_1.Text });`

I need to Patch only if input or selection field/s are not blank.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to remove all values by trimming then do the check like so:

```
If(!IsBlank(Trim(TextInput5_1.Text)), Patch(BookingTest,
{ Title: title, EventDate: TextInput5_1.Text });
```

Just time to concat the rest of the values now...